# SSL Cert for AWS Client-Side VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, vpn, certificate

We are in the process of migrating to AWS from Azure. I want to use a client-side VPN on AWS instead of a Bastion. Can I create a separate SSL cert for the AWS VPN using the same domain name that's used on Azure? For example our Azure site hosts our www.example13.com web apps.  Is it possible to obtain a separate cert, from a separate CA, for *.example13.com to use with our VPN service, vpn.example13.com?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS you'll need to request a certificate through the [Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/). When requesting a certificate you can verify domain ownership through DNS or email.